# Is there a way that I can convert all my materials into one texture?

Tags: texturing, materials, export

So I'm a Roblox modeler and I'm trying to create a texture for a model. I accidentally used materials and now I cant export the texture.  Is there a way that I can convert all my materials into one texture? I've tried nearly everything on YouTube but I don't have the time to remake this whole model. Anyone able to help?

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is "baking" textures, did you look that up ?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MH7Xdol5erw

Comment: hmmm this doesnt seem to work for me but thannks for pointing it out

Comment: wait nvm! it works!